# App Bar with picture inside

Tags: android, android-layout

Sorry for asking but I'm new in Android developing and havn't got enought reputation to ask under an exisiting Question.

I want to have an ActionBar with a picture in it. It should look like here (only without the Fav):

[image]

So I have to use a blank layout with a AppBar inside. Have I to inflate it? The rest have to be a LinearLayout with FrameLayouts inside, or?

Hope you can help me how to get the picture there inside!

Comment: The question is not clear. You have done the top layout and you want to know how to do the other views at the bottom?

Comment: I havn't done anything until now because all my tries dosn't Work. My first question is how do I get this picture there at top?

Comment: You can achieve it using the android design library look at this project https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare for a demo of exactly what you want to do.